# TSQL - How to use a case statement for 2 columns?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to do a case on the result of 2 columns. How do I do this?

e.g.:

```
SELECT CASE amount=100 AND DATE IS NOT NULL WHEN 0 THEN 'Something' ELSE ''
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
select case
    when amount = 100 and date is not null then 'something'
    else 'something else'
    end
```

This is a "searched case expression" ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)):

```
    CASE
      WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
      [ ELSE else_result_expression ]  END
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select someColumnName,
       case 
         when amount = 100  AND someothercondition then 'XXX'
         when amount = 1000  AND anothercondition then 'YYY'
         else 'WWW' 
       end as "MyColumnName"
from myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
case 
    when 
        amount = 100 
        and date is not null    
    then 
        '0'
    else 
        'something else'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for `SELECT WHEN`

https://web.archive.org/web/20210728081626/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/102704-1.shtml

Answer (score -2):

select case when amount = 100 and date is not null then 'something' else 'something 
when amount=0 then 'something else' end as MyColumnName